# dataRequested pass variable in XML

Tags: sapui5

Just wondering how do I pass a `this` or other variables in `dataRequested` and `dataReceived` in XML events? Something like the below:

```xml
<Select items="{
  path: '/Countries',
  events: {
    dataRequested: '.onCountriesRequested($source)',
    dataReceived: '.onCountriesReceived($source)',
    change: '.onCountriesChange'
  }
}">
```

Comment: I think this is a valid enhancement request. Create an issue at https://github.com/SAP/openui5 and let's see what the maintainers say. This would at least improve the development experience and consistency if the same rules as those in the topic [Handling Events in XML Views](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/b0fb4de7364f4bcbb053a99aa645affe) are applied to the `events`.

Answer (score 0):

'this' is the scope of your controller on which your view.xml is attached.

You can directly control everything related to your Select UI element in the related file Detail.controller.js or App.controller.js.

Just add an event listener in your UI element such as:

```
change="onCountriesChange"
```

Then define the function "onCountriesChange" in the corresponding controller.js, for example:

```
onCountriesChange : function(oEvent) {console.log(this);}
```

Or you can simply bind 'this' to your event handler by attaching it at the end of your function, for example

```
this.oVariable1 = "Test";
oSelect.attachEvent('dataReceived', function (oEvent) { 
   //write your logic here using this.oVariable1 for example
}.bind(this));
```